# Recursively capture identifier with the help of RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the following string:

```
 something, something, something, something, something shouldignore
```

The desired output would be: `[something, something, something, something, something]`. I came up with this RegExp `(^[\t ]+[^,\s]+)`, but it doesn't work for the other 4 `something`.

[Demo](https://regexr.com/469fh).

Comment: So you want to match the first 5 words? Should they all be the *same* words? Could you edit your question and give a bit more realistic examples of input and corresponding expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [back-references](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) for this, though I'm not sure why you need this (RE is not always the best solution!):

```
^[\t ]+([^,\s]+)(, \1)*
```

Here `\1` matches whatever group #1 captured.

[Online on RegExr](https://regexr.com/469g3).

Comment: But this is going to match only once, e.g: `[' something, something, something, something, something']`, and I'm trying to match `[' something', 'something', 'something', 'something', 'something']`. Makes sense?

Comment: @celoxxx I see what you mean, but I don't think you can get multiple matches from a single capture group in RE. Why do you want multiple matches if they all match the same content?

Comment: It is for a parser that uses Regular expressions to match tokens - I know that I could change the logic, but I'm now curious about this problem. I thought that it could be solved with the help of lazy match.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only matches the first part because you use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and are not repeating what you have already matched.

You could use your regex and add `(?:,\1)*` to the end so you repeat what you have already captured using a backreference. You could also move the anchor `^` out of the group and put it at the start.

`^([\t ]+[^,\s]+)(?:,\1)*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9Te0Z/1)

The you could split on a comma and trim the items in the resulting array:

```js
const str = " something, something, something, something, something shouldignore";

let res = str.match(/^([\t ]+[^,\s]+)(?:,\1)*/)[0]
    .split(',')
    .map(x => x.trim());

console.log(res);
```

If there can occur another `something` after `shouldignore`, you could split on an optional comma followed by 1+ whitespace characters `,?\s+` and filter out the ones that are not the same as the first item in the array returned from split:

```js
const str = " something, something, something, something, something shouldignore something";

let res = str.trim()
    .split(/,?\s+/)
    .filter((x, _, a) => x === a[0]);
console.log(res);
```